# LinqToSql query : deal with null values

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

Here's a Linq-to-SQL query to check in a SQL Server view if 2 values are present: an integer (`LOT`) and a string (`ART_CODE`).

But sometimes those values are `null` in the view. In that case I get an exception showing up on screen.

How can I modify this code to deal with null values?

```
private void ValidProdPlusLotBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int lot = Convert.ToInt32(NumLotTxtBox.Text);
    string artCode = ArtCodeLB.Content.ToString();

    try
    {               
        #region Qte Restant à produire
        DataClasses1DataContext dc2 = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        var reste = from r in dc.Vw_MajPoids_Restant
                    where r.LOT == lot && r.ART_CODE == artCode
                    select new
                           {
                                r.PnetRestant,
                                r.NbuRestant
                           };
        LotRestantTB.Text = reste.First().PnetRestant.ToString();
        NbuRestantTB.Text = reste.First().NbuRestant.ToString();
        #endregion
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        Messages.ErrorMessages($"{st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name}\n\n{ex.ToString()}");
    }                     
}
```

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve your issue yet?

Comment: Unfortunatly no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this which is working perfectly :

```
private void ValidProdPlusLotBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
int lot = Convert.ToInt32(NumLotTxtBox.Text);
string artCode = ArtCodeLB.Content.ToString();

try
{               
    #region Qte Restant à produire
    DataClasses1DataContext dc2 = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    var reste = from r in dc.Vw_MajPoids_Restant
                where r.LOT == lot && r.ART_CODE == artCode
                select new
                       {
                            r.PnetRestant,
                            r.NbuRestant
                       };
    if(!reste.Any())
    {
        // Do nothing
    }                  
    else
    {
        LotRestantTB.Text = reste.First().PnetRestant.ToString();
    NbuRestantTB.Text = reste.First().NbuRestant.ToString();
    }                  

    #endregion
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
    Messages.ErrorMessages($"{st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name}\n\n{ex.ToString()}");
}
```

}

If it can help someone else...